# How to hide default folders from Microsoft Outlook 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

I would like to hide the yellow highlighted folders from Microsoft Outlook 365. Unfortunately, when I right-click them, there isn't an according option. Does anybody know if there's any possibility to achieve it?

[image: Microsoft Outlook]

Comment: You can sort your folder tree and Archives will go to the bottom. I turn Conversations OFF (not helpful to me) and they do not show. The other ones I just ignore.

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided? Any update would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It’s suggested that you can try to use MFCmapi tool to hide the default folders:

[Hide the Folder](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/delete-outlooks-default-folders/#:%7E:text=return%20to%20Outlook.-,Hide%20the%20Folder,-The%20macro%20at)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.